# How to get my GROUP BY to take the value of the last row (by date) for a specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query which has a `GROUP BY` clause. This query takes employees "checkin" times from a `records` table and if the `dn` field on is **1** then the employee is in the office, but if it's **2**, then he/she left.

So lets say I put `records.dn` in the `GROUP BY` clause. This results with duplicate entries for each employee (I get their names one after the other in a table, twice).

I tried using MIN and MAX in the select, but that didn't make sense at all.

So from those multiple rows in the database where an employee might checkin and out multiple times, how do I take the LATEST row and use its `dn` field?

This is the query I'm talking about:

```
select 
    MAX(records.dn), 
    `records`.`din`, 
    `users`.`username`, 
    `users`.`id` as `user_id`, 
    DATE(records.created_at) AS date, 
    TIME(MIN(records.created_at)) AS first_log, 
    TIME(MAX(records.created_at)) AS last_log 
from `records` 
inner join `users` on `records`.`din` = `users`.`din` 
where records.created_at BETWEEN '2016-09-05 00:00:00' 
    AND '2016-09-08 00:00:00' 
group by `users`.`username`, DATE(records.created_at) 
order by `first_log` asc
```

(The first select column is  what I tried to do, using MAX)

This is the records table with some sample data:

[image: the table]

How do I achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: I have been in this situation yesterday. the best solution I have found is in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group/1313293#1313293

Comment: What are your Expected Results? A sqlfiddle never breaks anyone's heart :p

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick might do exactly what you want:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(r.dn order by created_at desc), ',', 1) as last_dn, 
       u.username, u.id as `user_id`, 
       DATE(r.created_at) AS date, 
       TIME(MIN(r.created_at)) AS first_log, 
       TIME(MAX(r.created_at)) AS last_log 
from records r inner join
     users u
     on r.din = u.din 
where r.created_at >= '2016-09-05' and
      r.created_at < '2016-09-08' 
group by u.username, DATE(r.created_at) 
order by first_log asc;
```

As written, this has three limitations:

1. It assumes that `dn` doesn't have a comma in it (that is easily fixed by using a different separator).
2. It assumes that the list of `dn`s for a user for a day won't exceed the maximum length of a string for `group_concat()`.  That can also be adjusted using a system parameter.
3. The `last_dn` is an string, even if that is not the original type.

But this trick works well in most cases.  The parameter `group_concat_max_len` is the size of the intermediate string.  Its default ([described](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) here) is 1,024.  This should be fine for up to a hundred or more integers.  It is a session parameter and easily changed.

Also note the following changes:

- I think unnecessary backticks in a query just make it harder to read.
- The use of table aliases makes a query easier to write and to read.
- I don't think you mean `between`, because it is inclusive.  I am guessing that you want date/time values strictly before the 8th.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm gonna try it shortly. Just a questions and clarification before I do that... What the maximum length for `group_concat()`? And this is a Laravel outputted query, so the framework adds the ticks by itself, I just copied it here :). the `between` clause with the dates is also dynamic -- I need it for a daterange picker.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `records`.`din`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`id` as `user_id`, DATE(records.cr' at line 1 (SQL: select substring_index(group_concat(records.dn order by created_at desc), , `records`.`din`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`id` as `user_id`, DATE(records.created_at) as date, TIME(MIN(records.created_at)) as first_log, TIME(MAX(records.created_at))

Comment: as last_log from `records` inner join `users` on `records`.`din` = `users`.`din` where records.created_at between '2016-09-05 00:00:00' and '2016-09-08 00:00:00' group by `users`.`username`, DATE(records.created_at) order by `first_log` asc)

Comment: @Aborted . . . Your syntax error does not correspond to the query in my answer.  There is no `records.din` in my query.

Comment: I removed `records.din`, added `substring_index(group_concat(records.dn order by created_at desc), ',', 1) as last_dn` and added ticks to `user_id`. With the way my query is built, I have no way of adding aliases (r and u) for the tables. Would that break the query?

Comment: That should be fine.  You should remove the `dn` column in the `group by` as well.